# How do I launch my server and client programs together?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Typically I will run three python files. i.e. I will manually run:

- runserver.py this will then wait while I run,
- white.py
- black.py

The game will not start unless I run all three files. The files do not run successively.i.e. runserver.py does not run then terminate and then white.py will start to run. It's suppose to run concurrently.

I wish to automate this process such that when I run runserver.py, I automatically run both white.py and black.py and the game can proceed.

Currently this is the code for runserver.py, it doesn't work however, the code launches the board but it doesn't seem to launch white.py or black.py:

```
board = board.Board()
white = server.Server(1)
black = server.Server(2)
board.playGame(white, black)

execfile("white.py")
execfile("black.py")
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on "it doesn't work".

Comment: the code launches the board, but it doesn't seem to load white.py or black.py

Comment: This is easily solved with a bash script: `(python runserver.py &); (python white.py &); (python black.py &); wait`

Comment: You should be passing strings `execfile("white.py")`

Comment: tried passing strings, but doesn't work. It gets stuck after launching the board, waiting for white.py and black.py to load.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `board.playGame` never returns, so execution never reaches your `execfile`. Use Matteo's solution or look at launching your board as [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)